# How to ask a person for a clarification about their question?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I wanted to answer a question, but I need some clarification about the problem. @undo has deleted my answer even after the user has replied it. Do somebody has an idea about it?

Comment: Do you have a link you can share? It is hard to address this without one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post comments querying for more information as answers.

You also cannot post comments on posts you're not primarily involved with with less then 50 points of reputation.

> @undo has deleted my answer even after the user has replied it.

You didn't link to the particular case, but elected (♦) moderators can convert such answers to comments, or just delete them single handedly.